# Function not running unless I refresh the page

Tags: php, json, ajax, facebook-login

I have implemented Facebook login in my website, by copying the JSON code from the Facebook Developers website. I have customized that code, adding an Ajax that calls a PHP file with some functions to insert the data returned by Facebook into our database.

When a user clicks into the "login with Facebook" button, a function called **facebookLogin()** runs. Inside that function, I have the Ajax that calls the PHP code. The data is not being inserted into the database unless I manually refresh the page. I have tried to refresh it automatically with a JavaScript function but it didn't work. I have searched for a solution to avoid that manually refresh, but with no success.

**I paste here the code. That's the extract of the code with the function described.**

```
  function facebookLogin() { // función que devuelve datos de usuarios
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {

        var nombreUsuario = JSON.stringify(response.name);
        nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario.replace(/\"/g, "");
        //document.getElementById("nombreUsuario").innerHTML = nombreUsuario;

        var emailUsuario = JSON.stringify(response.email);
        emailUsuario = emailUsuario.replace(/\"/g, "");

        var idFacebook = JSON.stringify(response.id);
        idFacebook = idFacebook.replace(/\"/g, "");
        var fotoPerfil = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + idFacebook + '/picture?type=large';
        //document.getElementById("fotoPerfilUsuario").src = fotoPerfil;

        //me            Se va a la api de Facebook, y devuelve los valores que el usuario aprueba.
        //              En nuestro caso, los datos que usamos son los siguientes:

        //name          Devuelve el nombre.
        //email         Devuelve el email del usuario.
        //picture       Devuelve la foto de perfil del usuario.

        // ----------   EMPIEZA FUNCIÓN AJAX   ---------- //

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/users/functions/pasardatosfb.php",
            async: false,
            data: { "nombreUsuario" :  nombreUsuario, "emailUsuario" : emailUsuario, "fotoPerfil" : fotoPerfil, "idFacebook" : idFacebook, "action" : "enviarDatosFb" },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                console.log(data); // Printa los datos que se pasan a Datos Login; es decir, los INSERT MySQLi.
            }
        });
});}
```

**And that's the PHP code that is called via Ajax in the code above:**

```
<?php
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/session_start.php'); // Incluimos el Session start.

if ($_POST['action'] == "enviarDatosFb"){
    $idFacebook = $_POST["idFacebook"];
    $nickUsuario = $_POST["nombreUsuario"];
    $emailUsuario = $_POST["emailUsuario"];
    $fotoPerfil = $_POST["fotoPerfil"];
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
    $fechaRegistroUsuario = strftime( "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S", time() );
    $idPermisosUsuario = "1";
    $totalMonedasUsuario = "1001";
    $idEstadoCuenta = "1";

    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO dtUsuariosDAG (nickUsuario, emailUsuario, fechaRegistroUsuario, idPermisosUsuario, totalMonedasUsuario, idEstadoCuenta)
    VALUES  ('$nickUsuario', '$emailUsuario', '$fechaRegistroUsuario', '$idPermisosUsuario', '$totalMonedasUsuario', '$idEstadoCuenta')
    ";

    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    }

    $sql2 = "
    SELECT idUsuario FROM dtUsuariosDAG
    ORDER BY idUsuario DESC LIMIT 1
    ";

    $result = $connection->query($sql2);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $idUsuario = $row['idUsuario'];
        }
    }

    $sql3 = "
    INSERT INTO dtInformacionUsuarios (idUsuario, fotoUsuario)
    VALUES ('$idUsuario', '$fotoPerfil')
    ";

    if ($connection->query($sql3) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql3 . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    }

    $sql4 = "
    INSERT INTO dtLoginRedesSociales (idUsuario, idRedSocial, tipoRedSocial)
    VALUES ('$idUsuario', '$idFacebook', '1')
    ";

    if ($connection->query($sql4) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql4 . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    }

    //TOCA AQUI
    $sqlHistorialBonus = "SELECT fechaSuceso FROM dtHistorialMonedas
    WHERE idUsuario=$idUsuario AND idMotivo=5 ORDER BY fechaSuceso DESC
    LIMIT 1";


    $resultadoHistorialBonus = $connection->query($sqlHistorialBonus);
    $rowBonus = $resultadoHistorialBonus->fetch_assoc();


    $fechaUltimoBonus = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($rowBonus['fechaSuceso']));


    $_SESSION['fechaUltimoBonus'] = $fechaUltimoBonus;

    $_SESSION["nickUsuario"] = $nickUsuario;
    $_SESSION["email"] = $emailUsuario;
    $_SESSION["idFacebook"] = $idFacebook;
    $_SESSION['idPermisosUsuario'] = $idPermisosUsuario;
    $_SESSION['idUsuario'] = $idUsuario;

    mysqli_close($connection);

}?>
```

Edit: I call the function facebookLogin in that button:

```
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState()" id="loginFb"></fb:login-button>
```

The function checkLoginState() calls inside the facebookLogin one:

```
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
      facebookLogin();
      location.reload();
    });
```

}

Comment: You should add the output off your your `console.log();` calls. And how / where are you calling your `facebookLogin()` function?

Comment: The button to log into Facebook calls a function called checkLoginState, and inside it calls the function facebookLogin() one. And the console.log() is printing the SQL query that the PHP code inserts into the database.

Comment: How is that possible? You only echo the sql when there is an error so either there is an error or the php is not getting parsed.

Comment: In the Ajax code, inside the facebookLogin() function, I have that:   success: function (data){console.log(data);}. That is printing the SQL query into the console.